# Training some variables in a restored TensorFlow model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a TensorFlow (TF) model that I'd like to restore and retrain **some of its parameters**. I know that `tf.get_operation_by_name('name of the optimizer')` retrieves the original optimizer that was used to train the model before it was stored. However, I don't know how to pass the new list of TF variables that I want the optimizer to retrain!

This example helps illustrate what I want to do:

```
learning_rate = 0.0001
training_iters = 60000
batch_size = 64
display_step = 20
ImVecDim = 784# The number of elements in a an image vector (flattening a  28x28 2D image)
NumOfClasses = 10
dropout = 0.8

with tf.Session() as sess:
   LoadMod = tf.train.import_meta_graph('simple_mnist.ckpt.meta')  # This object loads the model
   LoadMod.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./')) # Loading weights and biases and other stuff to the model
   g = tf.get_default_graph()

   # Variables to be retrained:
   wc2 = g.get_tensor_by_name('wc2:0')
   bc2 = g.get_tensor_by_name('bc2:0')
   wc3 = g.get_tensor_by_name('wc3:0')
   bc3 = g.get_tensor_by_name('bc3:0')
   wd1 = g.get_tensor_by_name('wd1:0')
   bd1 = g.get_tensor_by_name('bd1:0')
   wd2 = g.get_tensor_by_name('wd2:0')
   bd2 = g.get_tensor_by_name('bd2:0')
   out_w = g.get_tensor_by_name('out_w:0')
   out_b = g.get_tensor_by_name('out_b:0')
   VarToTrain = [wc2,wc3,wd1,wd2,out_w,bc2,bc3,bd1,bd2,out_b]

   # Retrieving the optimizer:
   Opt = tf.get_operation_by_name('Adam')

  # Retraining:
  X = g.get_tensor_by_name('ImageIn:0')
  Y = g.get_tensor_by_name('LabelIn:0')
  KP = g.get_tensor_by_name('KeepProb:0')
  accuracy = g.get_tensor_by_name('NetAccuracy:0')
  cost = g.get_tensor_by_name('loss:0')
  step = 1
  while step * batch_size < training_iters:
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
  #########################################################################
  #     Here I want to pass (VarToTrain) to the optimizer (Opt)!          #
  #########################################################################          
            if step % display_step == 0:
                acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: batch_xs, Y: batch_ys, KP: 1.})
                loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: batch_xs, Y: batch_ys, KP: 1.})
                print("Iter " + str(step * batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + "{:.6f}".format(
                    loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + "{:.5f}".format(acc))
            step += 1
  feed_dict = {X: mnist.test.images[:256], Y: mnist.test.labels[:256], KP: 1.0}
  ModelAccuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict)
  print('Retraining finished'+', Test Accuracy = %f' %ModelAccuracy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have not figured out a way to do what I want exactly, but I've found a way around the problem; instead of passing a new list of variables to the original optimizer, I defined a new optimizer with those variables passed to its `minimize()` method. The code is given below:

```
learning_rate = 0.0001
training_iters = 60000
batch_size = 64
display_step = 20
ImVecDim = 784# The number of elements in a an image vector (flattening a  28x28 2D image)
NumOfClasses = 10
dropout = 0.8

with tf.Session() as sess:
   LoadMod = tf.train.import_meta_graph('simple_mnist.ckpt.meta')  # This object loads the model
   LoadMod.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./')) # Loading weights and biases and other stuff to the model
   g = tf.get_default_graph()
# Retraining:
  X = g.get_tensor_by_name('ImageIn:0')
  Y = g.get_tensor_by_name('LabelIn:0')
  KP = g.get_tensor_by_name('KeepProb:0')
  accuracy = g.get_tensor_by_name('NetAccuracy:0')
  cost = g.get_tensor_by_name('loss:0')

######################## Producing a list and defining a new optimizer ####################################
  VarToTrain = g.get_collection_ref('trainable__variables')
  del VarToTrain[0] # Removing a variable from the list
  del VarToTrain[5] # Removing another variable from the list
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).\
                minimize(cost,var_list= VarToTrain)
##########################################################################################
  step = 1
  while step * batch_size < training_iters:
      batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
      sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: batch_xs, Y: batch_ys, KP: dropout})
      if step % display_step == 0:
            acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: batch_xs, Y: batch_ys, KP: 1.})
            loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: batch_xs, Y: batch_ys, KP: 1.})
            print("Iter " + str(step * batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + "{:.6f}".format(
                        loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + "{:.5f}".format(acc))
            step += 1
   feed_dict = {X: mnist.test.images[:256], Y: mnist.test.labels[:256], KP: 1.0}
   ModelAccuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict)
   print('Retraining finished'+', Test Accuracy = %f' %ModelAccuracy)
```

The code above did the job, but it has some issues! First, for some reason, I keep getting error messages every time I define a similar optimizer to the original one, `tf.train.AdamOtimizer()`. The only optimizer that I can define without TF throwing me error messages is the `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer()`. The other issue in this solution is its inconvenience; in order to produce a list of the variables I want to train, I first have to produce a list of all trainable variables using `VarToTrain = g.get_collection_ref('trainable_variables')`, print them out, memorize the location of the unwanted variables in the list, then, delete them one by one using `del` method!! There must be a more elegant way to doing that. What I have done works fine only for small networks!!